# Multiple Consumer Single Producer Queue

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out this synchronizing problem in Python. I have one Producer thread and (optional) multiple consumer threads (Depends on command ie ./script sums.txt -c 10).
Now with 1 Producer and 1 Consumer there is no problem, cause the synchronizing is handled with Queue's.

Now the problem, with more then 1 Consumers threads, it could be possible that Thread 1 gets an item from the queue's and processes it. While Thread 2 doing the same but faster then Thread 1 and prints before thread 1. I Tried to simulate this problem with random timers.

My output now with random timers: "./script sommen.txt -c 2"
As you noticed the 2nd item from the queue is handled before the first item, doesn't happen a lot without the random timers cause the operations are very simple so threads are fast enough. Is there a way I can fix this problem? I thought about locks but that would make the program inefficient?

Another thing, what is the best way to clean up threads. I know when my queue's are done (sentinel value's) but whats a good way to clean up threads?

Thanks alot!

```
Consumers is set to: 2
I'm thread number: 4316991488 Read  (P): 12 + 90
I'm thread number: 4316991488 Read  (P): 420 / 20
I'm thread number: 4316991488 Read  (P): 12 + 90
I'm thread number: 4316991488 Read  (P): 420 / 20
Monitor is done
I'm thread number: 4329586688 Write (C): 420 / 20 = 21.0
I'm thread number: 4324331520 Write (C): 12 + 90 = 102
```

--

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import threading
import operator
import sys
import queue
import optparse
from time import sleep
import random

def optionsparser():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser(
        usage="usage: %prog file [Options]")
    parser.add_option("-c", "--consumer", dest="consumer", type="int",
                      help="consumer <ident> [default: %default]")

    parser.set_defaults(consumer=1)
    opts, files = parser.parse_args()

    filename = files[0]

    try:
        _f = open(filename)
        return(filename, opts.consumer)
    except IOError:
        print ('Oh dear I/O Error')

def readitems(filename):

    print("Read from file: ", filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
    f.close()

    try: 
        for _line in mylist:
            data = _line.split(' ')

            qprint.put(data) #write to monitor queue
            qsum.put(data) #write to consumer queue

    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print(err)
    finally:
        qsum.put("Done Flag")
        qprint.put("Done Flag")
def consumer(qsum):

    while qsum:
        sleeptime = random.randint(1,10)
        sleep(sleeptime)
        try:
            if qsum.get() == "Done Flag":
                print("Monitor queue empty", threading.get_ident())
                ## Clean up
                # Put bakc for other consumers
                qsum.put("Done Flag")
                #cleanup here

            else:
                data = qsum.get()
                operator = calc(data)

        except EnvironmentError as Err:
            print(Err)

def calc(data):

    try:
        sleeptime = random.randint(1,10)
        sleep(sleeptime)
        getal1, diff, getal2 = data
        getal1 = int(getal1)
        getal2 = int(getal2)

        if diff == '+':
            print("I'm thread number:", threading.get_ident(), "Write (C):", str(getal1), diff, str(getal2), "=",  operator.add(getal1, getal2))
        elif diff == '-':
            print("I'm thread number:", threading.get_ident(), "Write (C):", str(getal1), diff, str(getal2), "=",  operator.sub(getal1, getal2))
        elif diff == '*':
            print("I'm thread number:", threading.get_ident(), "Write (C):", str(getal1), diff, str(getal2), "=",  operator.mul(getal1, getal2))
        elif diff == '/':
            print("I'm thread number:", threading.get_ident(), "Write (C):", str(getal1), diff, str(getal2), "=",  operator.truediv(getal1, getal2))
        elif diff == '%':
            print("I'm thread number:", threading.get_ident(), "Write (C):", str(getal1), diff, str(getal2), "=",  operator.mod(getal1, getal2))
        elif diff == '**':
            print("I'm thread number:", threading.get_ident(), "Write (C):", str(getal1), diff, str(getal2), "=",  operator.pow(getal1, getal2))
        else:
            print("I'm thread number:", threading.get_ident(), "Write (C):", str(getal1), diff, str(getal2), "=", "Unknown operator!")

    except ZeroDivisionError as Err:
        print(Err)
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong input")

def producer(reqs):  
    try:
        readitems(reqs)
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)


def monitor(qprint):

    while qprint:
        try:
            if qprint.get() == "Done Flag":

                print("Monitor is done")
            else:
                data = (qprint.get())
                getal1, diff, getal2 = data
                print("I'm thread number:", threading.get_ident(), "Read  (P):", str(getal1), diff, str(getal2))
        except RuntimeError as e:
            print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        reqs = optionsparser() 
        #create queu's
        qprint = queue.Queue()
        qsum = queue.Queue()
        #monitor threads
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=monitor, args=(qprint,))
        t2.start()
        #create consumers threads 
        thread_count = reqs[1]
        print("Consumers is set to:", thread_count)
        for i in range(thread_count):
            t = threading.Thread(target=consumer, args=(qsum,))
            t.start()

        #start producer 
        producer(reqs[0])

    except RuntimeError as Err:
        print(Err)
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using threads is efficient when task can be split and threaten independantly. If you want to use thead, keep in mind that parallelizing code is more efficient when there is no or few lock point in the code. A lock point can be a shared ressource.

In your case you just produce / consume data and you want it synchronized. It will be more efficient if you run this code sequencially, otherwise you ll have to define more accurately what task can benefit from paralelization.

Answer (score 0):

First: don't use Python threads to speed up CPU-bound tasks, like calculations. You will never see anything but a slowdown. [Because GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Do use Python threads for I/O-bound tasks, like URL fetching.

If you want results arrive in the order of posting, give every queue element a serial number. This way every task will know where its result belongs.

Use an ordered collection (e.g. a list) to put the results that worker threads produce, using the serial numbers as indices. Since potentially you can receive the results in reverse order, you need to store them all (cannot stream them).

I don't see why use locking here. First, locks defeat the purpose of parallel processing by blocking otherwise independent workers. Second, locks are hard and prone to subtle errors. Queues are way friendlier.